# Default working directory in Clion

Tags: clion

How to change default working directory in Clion EAP on the Mac?
Every time when I create new project, I need to change it to project location.

Comment: I can not believe this is still unsolved :(  I guess a symlink will have to do :(

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not possible to change the working directory through the GUI of CLion (see second question in "CMake configuration" section in [Source](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/)) but you can ask the developers to add this feature in the future (see [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-96)).

On the other hand, as far as I know, it is not possible to automatically add `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")` in the CMakeList.txt, but if I find a solution, I will write it here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still having this problem?

I just tried the following: I closed all of my projects to get back to the "Welcome to CLion" dialog. I selected "New Project" from the Quick Start menu on the right. This brings up a "New CMake Project" dialog. I then entered a new path under Project Location. The last segment of the project is interpreted as the Project Name

[image: Specify a New Project Location]. Click OK to create the new project.

The next time you create a new project, it should remember the location as shown here.

[image: Another New Project]

Comment: Problem still unsolved.
I meant that I need to change working directory(Run->Edit Configurations...->Working directory)
You asked this before [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834878/how-do-i-change-the-working-directory-for-my-program), but I need to set here the project location by default.

Comment: it is helped to me to add this line

`set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")`
but I don't know how to add it to cmake automatically when I create new project

Comment: I looked all over for the CMAKE template and it must be in code, alas.