# CLion C++ can't read/open plain file in project directory

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have .in file in project directory when i use absolute path to open the file it works but relative path not working.

directoy content

```
main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
milk2.in
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(project)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES  main.cpp )
add_executable(project ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

pair<int, int> periods[5000];
int lineCount = 0;
freopen("milk2.in", "r", stdin);

cin >> lineCount;


for (int j = 0; j < lineCount; ++j) {

    cin >> periods[j].first >> periods[j].second;

}

int startNode = periods[0].first, endNode = periods[0].second, milkMax = 0, freeMax = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < lineCount; ++i) {
    if (periods[i].first <= endNode) {
        endNode = periods[i].second;
        if ((endNode - startNode) > milkMax)
            milkMax = endNode - startNode;
    } else {
        if ((periods[i].first - endNode) > freeMax)
            freeMax = periods[i].first - endNode;
    }
}

cout << milkMax << " " << freeMax << endl;

}
```

there is no errors in the code but can,t read files contents with relative path.

Comment: `when i use absolute path to open the file it works but relative path not working.` - This is because your `.in` file is located in *source* directory, but executable is created in *build* directory. Same problem is described in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495311/clion-c-cant-read-open-txt-file-in-project-directory?rq=1) with very similar title.

Comment: My searches for this topic all land me here despite it being considered a duplicate. There's a nice way to control what folder the executable uses for file I/O. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632888/165164

Answer (score 2):

That is because the run-time directory is not the same as the project source directory.

The simplest solution I could think of is to define a macro that equals the project source directory, have the program change its working directory to that, and then open the files.

To do that you need to modify the `CMakeLists.txt` file like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(project)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(SOURCE_FILES  main.cpp )
add_executable(project ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_compile_definitions(project
    PUBLIC -DPROJECT_DIRECTORY="${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
```

And then in your `main.cpp` file:

```
// Header file for chdir call
#ifdef __linux__
# include <unistd.h>
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
# include <direct.h>
#endif

int main() {
#ifdef __linux__
    chdir(PROJECT_DIRECTORY);
#endif
#ifdef _WIN32
    _chdir(PROJECT_DIRECTORY);
#endif

    // Rest of code here...
}
```

Comment: You can change the exe's working directory without having to edit the build files. Please see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48632888/165164