# How to fix function (that validates input) from not reading a text file?

Tags: c, clion

Whenever I enter a text file for my program to read I always get the message:

```
Unable to open file: big_file.txt
Ending program.
```

I am not sure what part of the program is not working. I assume that it is either something in main() or validate_input() functions:

```
FILE* validate_input(int argc, char* argv[]){

    FILE* fp = NULL;

    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Not enough arguments entered.\nEnding program.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(argc > 2){
        printf("Too many arguments entered.\nEnding program.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Unable to open file: %s\nEnding program.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(0);
    }

    return fp;

}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char** lines = NULL;
    int num_lines = 0;
    FILE* fp = validate_input(argc, argv);

    read_lines(fp, &lines, &num_lines);
    print_lines(lines, num_lines);
    free_lines(lines, num_lines);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the program to output each line of a given text with a number in front counting each line, but every time I input a file it claims it cannot be read.

UPDATE:
When I add `fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));`

my output is:

```
Unable to open file big_file.txt: No such file or directory
```

but the file is on my desktop.

Not sure if this is the right place for the file but here it is:
[image]

Comment: Try `fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file %s: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));`. What do you get?

Comment: Are you sure the file exist? (this code is quite simple, I'm starting looking at the most simple things ;) ) And add `perror("fopen");` in the `if (fp==NULL)`, it while give you some info

Comment: @melpomene it says "errno" is an undeclared identifier, what should it be?

Comment: include `#include <errno.h>`

Comment: @Phantom I updated my question with the output I get.  I am not sure why it is saying there is no such file when I have the file on my desktop.

Comment: @Christina Is it in the directory where you are running your program?

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: @Phantom I am using Clion for the code & it is in the same folder as my project is saved in.

Comment: @Christina Is it in the same directory that the executable is in? (Also, what OS are you on?)

Comment: @Christina In Clion, is there an option to tell it where to find files? In the if, print the current dir (`char *getwd(char *buf);`, in `#include <unsitd.h>`)

Comment: Most IDE's have a setting that determines the current working directory when the code is run. See [How do I change the working directory for my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834878/)

Comment: @Christina, it appears that the executable (not the project) and the text files are not present in the same directory. Please either keep both the files in the same directory, or give the complete path+file name of the file in the command line.

Comment: By default, your program runs from `cmake-build-debug`, so that's where it'll look for files.