# How do I change the CMakeLists.txt working directory for my SFML program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, sfml

I have graphics files that are not loading because me program generate by CMakeLists.txt is opening in `"/Users/icookiez"`, not in my source directory (`/Users/icookiez/Documents/Studia/Projekt C++/hit-the-bucket/`). I've try "[How do I change the working directory for my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834878/how-do-i-change-the-working-directory-for-my-program)", but nothing happened.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(Hit-The-Bucket) # VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES CXX

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS graphics audio REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}) # Solution from "How do I change the working directory for my program"

add_executable(Hit-The-Bucket main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Hit-The-Bucket sfml-graphics sfml-window)
```

And my files structure is

```
/Users/icookiez/Documents/Studia/Projekt C++/hit-the-bucket\
    CMakeLists.txt
    main.cpp
    assets\
        fonts\
            ...
        images\
            ...
```

What should I change in my CMakeLists.txt so ma program is opening at `/Users/icookiez/Documents/Studia/Projekt C++/hit-the-bucket/`

Comment: You likely don't set this in the `CMakeLists.txt`. What you do may depend on your IDE.

Comment: I'm writing in VS code and know working directory from c++ ```cout```:

```c++
...
#include <filesystem>
...
std::cout << "Current path is " << std::filesystem::current_path() << '\n';
...
```

And output is:

```bash
...
Failed to load font "./assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf" (failed to create the font face)
Current path is "/Users/icookiez"
Failed to load image "./assets/images/main_background.png". Reason: Unable to open file
...
```

Comment: I think you need to alter the settings in the `launch.json` file. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623138/vscode-how-to-set-working-directory-for-debug)

Comment: I'm not sure. becouse when i run this via `g++ -c main.cpp && g++ main.o -o hit-the-bucket -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system && ./hit-the-bucket`, it is working fine

Comment: .. because then you are already in the correct directory. You need to configure the `cwd` in your `launch.json` file, as @drescherjm said. You could set it to `"${workspaceRoot}"` for example.