# ifstream file won't open in C++

Tags: c++, clion, readfile, ifstream, c++98

so i wrote the following code:

```
DnaSequence fetchSequence(const string& fileName){
    string sequence,line;

    ifstream inFile(fileName);

    inFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while(inFile) {
        getline(inFile, line);
        sequence.append(line);
    }
    inFile.close();
    DnaSequence seq(sequence);
    return seq;
}


int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {

    DnaSequence dnaS = fetchSequence("readFrom.txt");


    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

and for some reason it does not reach the code inside the while statement which means the file is not opened correctly although it's in the same directory what you think the problem might be?

Comment: Often the problem comes down to [the same directory as what?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)

Comment: use `is_open` to see if the file was actually opened

Comment: Side note: C++98 usually can't open a file stream from a `std::string`. That ability was added in the C++11 Standard revision.

Comment: @user4581301 so what are my alternatives?

Comment: as @user4581301 stated, is your file in the same directory as your executable ?

Comment: Are you running the program in an IDE? If so, add the IDE (and probably the version) to the question. Someone will know how to configure the working directory or tell you where the working directory is so you can move the text file into it.

Comment: yeah is it a problem? @magmine

Comment: ***yeah is it a problem?*** That would be a problem if you are running Visual Studio Community (or one of the paid versions) since the default folder in those IDEs is the Project directory. However with that said many IDEs set the working directory to the same as the project.

Comment: @AladinHandoklo IDE being used is... ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Clion

Comment: [Probably going to find this helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834878/how-do-i-change-the-working-directory-for-my-program).

Comment: I don't know CLion but added the tag

Comment: Make sure your file is actually readfrom.txt and not readfrom.txt.txt. Windows users can easily get this wrong because the file explorer hides extensions of known files by default and that can make it more difficult to know if your file has a .txt or a .txt.txt extension

Comment: @drescherjm i made sure it's the right syntax, also i'am using Ubuntu system

Comment: isn't there an alternative way to deal with files in C++98 ?

Comment: Are you sure c++98 supports this: `ifstream inFile(fileName);`, however that would be a compile error preventing your program from being built. I am not sure that your compiler is in c++98 mode.

Comment: never mind guys found the problem i had two executable files since i had my own make file so i was running the wrong executable file which was in a different directory, problem solved thanks for helping me realise what it is.

Comment: Probably just delete the question. It won't help future readers